# Pivot Table vs. Pivot Cache

Tags: vba, excel

What is the difference between refreshing a pivot table and refreshing the underlying pivot cache?

In other words, is there a difference between

```
PivotTable.PivotCache.Refresh
PivotTable.RefreshTable
```

Comment: Refresh Table takes the cache and applies it to the table, Refresh Cache fetches the data from the original, possibly remote, data source.

Comment: @PhillipH So if the Pivot Cache refers to local data that has changed, will refreshing the table reflect those changes?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A PivotCache object can support many PivotTables so refreshing the former refreshes all its supported tables.

Refreshing a PivotTable supported by a particular PivotCache object does not refresh all the other PivotTable objects that hang off it.

Comment: Would be nice to see some source documents on this answer.  Good legacy question.